# Lift simulator Python

Tags: python

The error at the moment is here: `cust_list.append(customer(i, floor_count))`, it says that the name `customer` is not defined. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

This program is quite basic in its design (I'm pretty new on the subject to be honest) and at the moment the lift goes up to the top and back down again. The program works until after you enter in the floors/customers, then it crashes.

```
import random

def main():
    customer_count=int (input("how many customers?:"))
    floor_count =int (input("How many floors?:"))

    cust_list=[]
    for i in range(1, customer_count+1):
        cust_list.append(customer(i, floor_count))

        lift=Lift(floor_count, cust_list)
        building=Building(floor_count, cust_list, lift)


class Building(object):
    def __init__(self, num_of_floors, customer_list, lift):
        self.customers=customer_list
        self.total_floors=num_of_floors
    def work(self):
        while elevator.floor !=0:
            for customer in self.customers:
                if elevator.floor==customer.on_floor:
                    elevator.reg_list.append(customer)
                    customer.indicator=1
                elif elevator.floor==customer.going_floor:
                    elevator.reg_list.remove(customer)
                    customer.indicator=0
                    customer.fin=1
            elevator.move()

class Customers(object):
    def __init__(self, iden, num_of_floors, curnt_floor, dest_floor,
    in_lift, finished=0):     
        self.id=iden
        self.indicator=in_lift
        self.fin=finished
        #self.cfloor=curnt_floor
        curnt_floor=random.randint(1, num_of_floors)
        self.on_floor=curnt_floor
        dest_floor=random.randint(1, num_of_floors)
        self.going_floor=dest_floor

class Lift(object):
    def __init__(self, num_of_floors, register_list, direction="up",
    curnt_floor=1): 
        self.total_floors=num_of_floors
        self.reg_list=[]
        self.floor=curnt_floor
        self.direct=direction
    def move(self):
        if self.total_floors==self.floor:
            self.direct="down"
        if self.direct=="up":
            self.floor+=1
        else:
            self.floor-=1
    def register_customer(self,customer):
        self.reg_list.append(customer)
    def done_customer(self, customer):
        self.reg_list.remove(customer)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: "customer" function has never being defined

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. When your question relates to a specific error message, please remember to always post the full traceback in your question.

Answer (score 0):

It says `customer is not defined` because you used the term `customer` before defining it. Look at all the code in `main()` before the line in question, and note that you never mentioned `customer`.